# jQuery ajax call not falling into success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jdbctemplate

I am new to doing jQuery ajax calls and am trying to test an ajax call I have attempted to write today. Here it is.

```
var heartbeatInterval = 30000;
var heartBeatTimer = null;
var retryCount = 0;
var maxRetries = 10;

$().ready(function () {

    var url = $.url("/pollBulletin.htm");
    heartBeatTimer = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            error: function (data) {

                retryCount = retryCount + 1;
                if (heartBeatTimer != null && retryCount >= maxRetries) {
                    clearInterval(heartBeatTimer);
                }
            },
            success: function (bulletinBarMessage) {

                retryCount = 0;
                var respContent = "";
                respContent += bulletinBarMessage.messageLevel + " : ";
                respContent += bulletinBarMessage.message;
            }
        });
        // When communication with the server is lost stop the heartbeat.
    }, heartbeatInterval);
});
```

At the moment the code is never falling into the success part of the call. Can someone confirm if it looks ok? I'm not sure if I have coded this right. I know the server side code is doing the write thing. At the moment it is just return a null (server side).

Server side...

```
public BulletinBarMessage getBulletinBarMessage() {
    JdbcTemplate select = this.getJdbcTemplate();
    List<BulletinBarMessage> messages = select.query(BULLETIN_LOOKUP_SQL, new BulletinBarMessageRowMapper());
    BulletinBarMessage bulletinBarMessage = null;

    if (messages != null && !messages.isEmpty()){
        bulletinBarMessage = (BulletinBarMessage)messages.get(0);
    }

    return bulletinBarMessage;
}
```

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: try putting in a complete: function() {} and see if thats fired..

Comment: looks fine did you opened a fiddler to acknowledge the request was sent to server?

Comment: Why not use the error function to print out any errors that may have occurred? Also read [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) so you know what arguments that function should actually have and what values are passed to them.

Comment: is the file pollBulletin.htm exists in the folder path specified on your server, please check your path /pollBulletin.htm

Comment: did you see anything in console (console.log) in success or error functions?

Comment: add complete event and put console.log in error, success and complete events then see what happens.
complete event fire whether request fail or success.

Comment: By default, `$.ajax` will attempt to auto-detect which format the server answer has. In my experience, this doesn't always work, and if it's detected wrong the `$.ajax` call will fail internally. Add the `dataType: 'text'` option to receive an unprocessed response. If `success()` still doesn't get called, the error is somewhere else.

Comment: thanks all for your help. The feedback about the success method was very useful as I hadn't heard about it before. I think the issue was the null values. If i populate the db columns to have data the call works fine.